# How to install or read Firefox binary for use with Selenium on Databricks?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, databricks, geckodriver

I'm trying to use Selenium with Firefox on Databricks but can't get it to work, and I haven't come across any others with quite the same issues as me. The problem seems to lie with the Firefox installation.

**My first approach** was to install Selenium, geckodriver and Firefox within the notebook. The first two installed fine, but the Firefox installation showed some network connection issues. Here's what I ran:

- Install Selenium

```
%pip install selenium
```

- Install geckodriver

```
%sh
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.31.0/geckodriver-v0.31.0-linux64.tar.gz -O /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz
```

```
%sh
tar -xvzf /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz -C /tmp
```

- Install Firefox

```
%sh
/usr/bin/yes | sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

which gives the error

```
Ign:1 https://apt.datadoghq.com stable InRelease 
Err:2 https://apt.datadoghq.com stable Release Could not handshake: Error in the pull function. [IP: xx.xxx.xx.xx xxx] 
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease Connection failed [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx xx] 
Hit:4 https://repos.azul.com/zulu/deb stable InRelease 
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease Connection failed [IP: xx.xxx.xx.xx xxx] 
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease Connection failed [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx xx] 
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease Connection failed [IP: xx.xxx.xx.xx xxx]
```

I tried skipping the `apt-get update` command and running

```
%sh
sudo apt-get --yes --force-yes install firefox
```

but it resulted in similar errors.

I later discovered that our databricks environment is set up in such a way that we can't send anything outside of our network, so this approach of installing Firefox will not work.

**My second approach** was to download and install Firefox to my local machine and upload the *firefox.exe* file to the dbfs. I installed selenium and the geckodriver as above and ran the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.binary_location = r'/dbfs/path/to/firefox/firefox.exe'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path = '/path/to/driver/geckodriver')
```

which gave the error

```
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path = '/path/to/driver/geckodriver')
InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable
```

It seems that for some reason, it can't read the *firefox.exe* file that I've uploaded to dbfs.

Any suggestions as to possible fixes for this? Or any alternative ways to get Selenium working with Firefox (taking the network restrictions in to account)?

Answer (score 0):

The error message from apt package manager shows it couldnt connect to pkg repository. Which indicates that you dont have access grated to that site. Might be some whitelisting issue, or firewall conn request item...

Look up "headless firefox setup" you might also need that to able to run firefox withough X windows system...

hope this helps, Zoltan

Comment: Thanks Zoltan. Yes, I've discussed whitelisting with the admin for our Databricks Workspace but it's unfortunately not an option so it won't be possible to install Firefox this way.